# Sort attribute table in an atlas layout with PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, print-composer, sorting

I wrote a script that automate the production of an atlas layout with PyQGIS 3 that works well but it remains a detail I can't figure out.

Each page of my atlas contains a map zoomed on a particular extent, and an attribute table presenting some key informations on the features visible on the map.

I would like to sort the attribute table according to the values of one attribute.

I know how to do it for a text table:

```
tab.sort(key=lambda x:x[0]) # to sort from the 1st column
```

But it doesn't work for the `QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable` class that has no attribute `sort`

I first thougth to "convert" my attribute table to a text table, but I am sure there is an easier and faster way to sort it. Like the attribute table change on each page, it will make the script too heavy for nothing.

**UPDATE**
The following code return a sorted attribute table displayed on my layout

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = "Atlas"
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()

layout.setName(layoutName)

manager.addLayout(layout)

pdf = project.mapLayersByName('plan_de_ferme')[0]
pdf_table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.create(layout)
pdf_table.setVectorLayer(pdf)
pdf_fields = ['champ','sup','supepnd']
pdf_table.setDisplayedFields(pdf_fields, True)
layout.addMultiFrame(pdf_table)
frame2 = QgsLayoutFrame(layout, pdf_table)
frame2.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(60.6, 153.3),True)
frame2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(213, 30.73, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
pdf_table.addFrame(frame2)

tblCol = QgsLayoutTableColumn()
tblCol.setAttribute('champ')
tblCol.setSortOrder(0) # 0 = Asc, 1 Desc
pdf_table.setSortColumns([tblCol])
layout.refresh()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find below a sample to do sorting using the "PyQGIS way" instead of the Python way.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()

layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName('Your layout name')
# You need to select in the layout GUI an existing
# "QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable" (in fact, insertion
# of a QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable insert it within
# a QgsLayoutFrame)
firstItemSelected = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0] # QgsLayoutFrame

frame = firstItemSelected.multiFrame() # Your QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable

# Part to do the sort using QGIS mecanism. Also available in the GUI of
# the layout (part "Item Properties", "Main properties", click on
# button "Attributes" and see "Sorting")

tblCol = QgsLayoutTableColumn()
tblCol.setAttribute('NAME') # First column name in your case. You can also put an expression
tblCol.setSortOrder(0) # 0 = Asc, 1 Desc

frame.setSortColumns([tblCol])
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that works great !